# Sending Static Memory 2D Array using MPI and C++

Tags: c++, mpi

I am having some trouble sending arrays using MPI. I currently have an array called positions of static memory. I gradually fill the array  in a recursive manner. Eventually, I send the array to slave processors to complete the filling.

```
const int SIZE = 8;
const int DEPTH = 3 ;

void recursion(int column, int positions[SIZE], int rank, int numtasks) {
  //other code
  positions[DEPTH] = row;
  MPI_Send(&positions, SIZE, MPI_INT, r, 1, MPI::COMM_WORLD) ;
  //other code }

int main() {
  int positions[SIZE];
  MPI::Init();
  rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
  numtasks = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
  char name[MPI::MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
  memset(name,0,MPI::MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME);
  MPI::Get_processor_name(name,len);
  memset(name+len,0,MPI::MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME-len);
  if(rank == MASTER) {
    recursion(0, positions, rank, numtasks); }
  if(rank != MASTER) {
  MPI_Recv(&positions, SIZE, MPI_INT, 0, MPI::ANY_TAG, MPI::COMM_WORLD, &stat);
```

Using the cout function, I managed to discover that the positions array before sending is :

```
0 2 4 0 1055625616 32621 4252832 0
```

The numbers after the second 0 are array spots that I have not filled yet. But the positions array after recv is:

```
-196000928 32767 -196001336 3 -1769860728 54 1047301632 32621
```

Even when I change the numbers on the array on the Master processor, the slave always receives the same array.

*Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong, and how to fix these arrays?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the line `MPI_Send(&positions, SIZE, MPI_INT, r, 1, MPI::COMM_WORLD);`. You should not use `&positions` but `positions` instead. `positions` type is `int *` and so `&positions` type is `int **` and you really are just sending garbage in this case instead of real array.

Comment: Thank you! I really want to send you internet cookies right now.

Comment: Note that this only applies to the `positions` argument of `recursion()`. In the main function `positions` and `&positions` are pointers having the same memory address though being of different types, therefore the `MPI_Recv` call works.